# Finding a function whose double covariant derivative is delta function

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-numbers

I have a function $f$ defined as $\frac{\overline{z}-\overline{w}}{(z-w)(1 + z\overline{z})(1+w\overline{w})}$.

I want to prove that $$\partial_{\overline{z}}^2 f + \frac{2z}{1+z\overline{z}}\partial_{\overline{z}}f = \pi \frac{2}{(1+ z\overline{z})^2}\delta(z-w).$$

This is basically a double covariant derivative wrt to $\overline{z}$ taking the metric in unit sphere in stereographic coordinates.

I found that $\partial_{\overline{z}}f = \delta(z-w)\frac{(1+z\overline{z})(\overline{z}-\overline{w})}{1+w\overline{w}} + \frac{1}{z-w}\frac{(1+2z\overline{z}-z\overline{w})}{1+w\overline{w}}$.

If I differentiate again I am encountering a derievative of a delta function which I do not know how to do.

But since I know the result I calculated back what the derivative of delta function should be a found out to be $\frac{2\delta(z-w)}{\overline{z}-\overline{w}}\frac{w\overline{w}-z\overline{z}}{1+z\overline{z}}$.

Basically during the calculation I used the product rule and took $\frac{1}{z-w}$ as one function and rest as another and did the diffrentiation.I also used the fact that $\partial_{\overline{z}}\frac{1}{z-w}=\delta(z-w)$.

I would like to know whether the procedure I have done is correct.Is the derivative of the delta function I have mentioned is correct or not.Pls help me.

This problem is basically involved during computing the BMS charge

Comment: -1. This is a purely mathematical question which belongs on Math SE. The context (computing BMS charge) has no impact on the question.

Comment: Notice that the $\delta$-function is being multiplied by ${\bar z} - {\bar w}$ so it is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note

$$
D_{\bar z}^2f = \gamma_{z\bar z} \partial_{\bar z}( \gamma^{z\bar z} \partial_{\bar z} f ) 
$$
We are solving the equation
\begin{align}
D_{\bar z}^2f &= \pi \gamma_{z\bar z} \delta^2(z-w)\\
\gamma_{z\bar z} \partial_{\bar z}( \gamma^{z\bar z} \partial_{\bar z} f ) &=  \pi \gamma_{z\bar z} \delta^2(z-w) \\
\partial_{\bar z}( \gamma^{z\bar z} \partial_{\bar z} f ) &=  \frac{1}{2} \partial_{\bar z} \frac{1}{z-w} \\
\gamma^{z\bar z} \partial_{\bar z} f  &=  \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{z-w} + g ( z,w,\bar w)\\
\partial_{\bar z} f  &=  \frac{1}{2} \frac{\gamma_{z\bar z} }{z-w} + \gamma_{z\bar z}  g( z,w,\bar w)
\end{align}

Note that we have

$$
f = \frac{ \bar z - \bar w}{ (z-w)(1+z\bar z)(1+w\bar w)}
$$

so that

$$
\partial_{\bar z} f =  \frac{ 2\pi \delta^2 ( z - w )( \bar z - \bar w )}{  (1+z\bar z)(1+w\bar w)}   +   \frac{1}{2} \frac{\gamma_{z\bar z} }{z-w} + \frac{1}{2} \gamma_{z\bar z} \frac{ \bar w }{ ( 1 + w \bar w ) } 
$$
The first term is zero. The rest of this is precisely the of the required form.

Comment: thank you prahar.This was exactly what I was looking for.i was confused when the dereivative of the $\delta$ came.But I didnt notice the fact that it is with factor of $\overline{z-w}$ so it will be zero.I guess the reason why this should be zero is when you are acting that on a test function you you get the integrand as zero right ?

Comment: @AnupamAh yep, that's right.

Comment: I have another doubt .How do you get the last piece from $f$.How does the $\frac{\overline{w}}{(1+w\overline{w})^2}$

Comment: @AnupamAh - There was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: @Prahar-Suppose I multiply $f$ by $\gamma^{z\bar z}$ will I get rid of the $\gamma_{z\bar z}$ in the double covariant derivative?What I thought was since the covariant derivative of metric is zero this will act as a constant and i can take it outside to cancel the $\gamma_{z\bar z}$ and get just the delta function.Am I thinking right ?

Comment: yes, you could. The equation would then read $D^z D_z f = \pi \delta^2(z-w)$.

Comment: What I actually meant was if $f$ is replaced by $\gamma^{z\overline{z}}f$ is $D_{\overline{z}}^2(\gamma^{z\overline{z}}f)=\gamma^{z\overline{z}}D_{\overline{z}}^2f$.Then $D_{\overline{z}}^2(\gamma^{z\overline{z}}f)=\pi \delta(z-w)$ right?

Comment: ah yes, that is correct. Let me just note since I just realized this - the indices are not matching up on both sides. This is super important because the index structure determines the way the covariant derivative acts on an object. Clearly, $f$ is not a function and must have index structure $f^{{\bar z}{\bar z}}$. You should be careful about this.

Comment: @Prahar-but the $f$
used in BMS supertranslations is just an function on sphere right?Does it have index structure?I think I am getting confused at what all places just the value of $\gamma_{z\overline{z}}$is used and where it is used as a metric tensor object.Can you please make this clear?